# Identifying non-intersecting (super-)sets

Tags: algorithm, set

I am looking for an algorithm to identify non-intersecting (super-)sets in a set of sets.

Lets, assume I have a set of sets containing the sets A, B, C and D, i.e. {A, B, C, D}. Each set may or may not intersect some or all of the other sets.

I would like to identify non-intersecting (super-)sets.

Examples:

- If A & B intersect and C & D intersect but (A union B) does not intersect (C union D), I would like the output of {(A union B), (C union D)}
- If only C & D intersect, I would like the output {A, B, (C union D)}

I am sure this problem has long been solved. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Even better would be of course if somebody had already done the work and had an implementation in python they were willing to share. :-)

Comment: What output do you want if A intersects B intersects C intersects D intersects A, but A,C and B,D do not intersect?  If you want (A union B union C union D) then I would turn this into finding the connected components of a graph.

Comment: I want (A union B union C union D). Thanks for the reference to graphs. Since you seem to have some experience, how would you structure the graph? Nodes are A, B, C, D and edges are intersections, am I understanding this right? BTW, if you make this an answer, even a short one, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would turn this from a set problem into a graph problem by constructing a graph whose nodes are the graphs with edges connecting sets with an intersection.

Here is some code that does it.  It takes a dictionary mapping the name of the set to the set.  It returns an array of sets of set names that connect.

```
def set_supersets (sets_by_label):
    element_mappings = {}
    for label, this_set in sets_by_label.items():
        for elt in this_set:
            if elt not in element_mappings:
                element_mappings[elt] = set()
            element_mappings[elt].add(label)
    graph_conn = {}
    for elt, sets in element_mappings.items():
        for s in sets:
            if s not in graph_conn:
                graph_conn[s] = set()
            for t in sets:
                if t != s:
                    graph_conn[s].add(t)

    seen = set()
    answer = []
    for s, sets in graph_conn.items():
        if s not in seen:
            todo = [s]
            this_group = set()
            while 0 < len(todo):
                t = todo.pop()
                if t not in seen:
                    this_group.add(t)
                    seen.add(t)
                    for u in graph_conn[t]:
                        todo.append(u)
            answer.append(this_group)
    return answer

print(set_supersets({
    "A": set([1, 2]),
    "B": set([1, 3]),
    "C": set([4, 5]),
    "D": set([3, 6])
}))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for even supplying code to go along with your suggestion!